# How to enable internet connection via bridge (Win 7 (host) - Debian (guest))?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian, bridge

I have Debian VM and can not ping it outside and access internet inside. The important requirement is have ip address to listen for the server which run on Debian.

By default my config looks as this

[image: Inital config]

My host machine ipconfig:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 4:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a8b6:1fcc:cc1e:84d8%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.106
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ef.com
Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1111:f5d3:1a86:f6b%19
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.15.107
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3828:a1eb:e880:5f76%20
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.106.2
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I added static ip to VM within my local network. After that looks like this:

[image: config with bridge]

However, I still don't able connect network form VM and can ping this ip from host machine either. Did I misunderstand something? Simply bridge in VM settings and ip within available list should be enough

Answer (score 0):

> Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

The clue is here, you need either bridged or NAT network. This is changed in the VM's network settings.

[This page](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) explains the options in detail.

Comment: Thank you for clue! My VM already configured network as bridge. Shall I configure something else? The page by link doesn't provide this info -- it iterate only what I already did.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.